# How to return a subset of data frame matching a parsed date string in a column

Tags: r

I have a csv file in the format:-

```
Date, Name, Age
20181021,  Name1, 80
20181022,  Name2, 79
20181023,  Name2, 79
```

I have read the csv file into a dataframe. I want to grab a subset of the file where the day is a Sunday.

If I Iterate the rows I can successfully see that the date is displayed as the days using:

```
 contents <- read.csv("c:/file.csv")

    for(i in 1:nrow(contents)) {
    row <- contents[i,]
    day <- weekdays(parse_date_time(toString(row$Date), orders = c("ymd")))
    print(day)
    }
```

However I would prefer to just do this using a subset (if possible)

```
sundayValues <- subset(contents , 
                       weekdays(parse_date_time(toString(contents $Date),
                       orders = c("ymd"))) == "Sunday")
```

Which returns: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

I'm pretty new to R so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data frame `contents` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end use `subset` like this.  No packages are used.

```
subset(contents, weekdays(as.Date(format(Date), "%Y%m%d")) == "Sunday")
##       Date   Name Age
## 1 20181021  Name1  80
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Date, Name, Age
20181021, Name1, 80
20181022, Name2, 79
20181023, Name2, 79"
contents <- read.csv(text = Lines)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that's perfect. Much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

If all your dates are in the format shown, you can do:

```
dates <- c(20100101:20100130)
newdates <- paste(substr(dates, 1, 4), substr(dates, 5, 6), substr(dates, 7, 8))
sundays <- which(weekdays(as.POSIXct(newdates)) == "Sunday")
```

Then you can subset using

```
data[sundays, ]
```